# "CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 10 seconds" HTTPS / SSL

Tags: ssl, https, nagios, nrpe, fedora-20

I have configured

- NAGIOS server on IP address AA.BB.CC.DD (Linux Fedora 20), and
- Monitoring the host with IP address LL.MM.NN.OO (Linux Fedora 20).

I have configured NRPE to run on port # 15666 on both the machines, and configured iptables.
I am accessing NAGIOS web interface securely over https (SSL) [e.g. (`https://AA.BB.CC.DD/nagios`)].

On the NAGIOS server, when I run the command, I can see the output:

```
sudo -u nagios /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H LL.MM.NN.OO -p 15666 -c check_total_procs
PROCS OK: 114 processes
```

So, it appears like NRPE is configured correctly.

However, when I check the host/services from the browser (https://AA.BB.CC.DD/nagios), I get an error `CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 10 seconds`.

Am I missing something?

Well, I have modelled my config files based on the examples in the book "Building a Monitoring Infrastructure with Nagios", and objecttricks.html on Sourceforge.

Here are the snippets from the config files anyways:

```
define command{
        command_name check_nrpe
        command_line $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
        }
```

and

```
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               SystemTest
        service_description     Total Processes
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_total_procs
        }
```

Remote host configuration:

/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg has:

```
command[check_network_security]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1:30 -C NetworkSecurity.bin
command[check_network_comm]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1:30 -C NetworkCommunication.bin
command[check_ping]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ping -H $ARG1$ -w $ARG2$ -c $AGR3$ -p 5
```

Comment: We'll need a fair bit more than this, though your investigation's a good start (+1 from me).  Could you **paste into your question** the relevant sections from the config files?  The bit where that particular test is defined against that particular host, and the bit where the `check_command` referenced therein is defined, would be most handy.

Comment: I have edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you decided to change the port that NRPE uses for some reason (the default is 5666), you have to change the command definition for `check_nrpe` to match.

So you'll need to add `-p 15666` to the command_line, at the very least.

(If you plan to run NRPE on this alternate port on every host, you can safely add the hard-coded port to the command def. But if you don't intend to do this, you might want to define a new command called `check_nrpe_port` (or similar) that accepts the port as $ARG2$ and leave the original intact.)

Comment: Whoa! How could I miss this? :) A good catch indeed. I missed -p 15666  in commands.cfg file.